# Will a ceramic capacitor work for a class-B amplifier output?

Tags: capacitor, amplifier, component-selection, ceramic

I am working on a project that uses a basic class-B amplifier design for lo-fi audio output (just plays some clicks and beeps through a small speaker as UI sounds). Here is my schematic:

[image]

For prototyping I have been using a 100 μF electrolytic capacitor. For the SMT production run I am looking at using a 100 μF ceramic cap for the smaller form factor.

Will switching to ceramic work for this design?

I'm not overly concerned with differences in audio quality, just that I still have a functional way of driving my small speaker.

Comment: Ceramic capacitors are pretty nonlinear, so do keep that in mind.

Comment: A ceramic cap might work.  At the same time, I doubt that a 100uF ceramic will have a smaller form factor than a 100uF electrolytic, voltage rating being equal.  There are SMT electrolytic cans.  SMT tantalum too.

Comment: not bothered by the horrendous power on click you get? coupling speakers via caps is a bit of a last resort in general.

Comment: It doesn't sound like you need any sort of "bass" response, so have you checked that smaller capacitors aren't sufficient? E.g., 22 μF or 33 μF.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The capacitor forms a highpass with the load impedance. Typically, AC coupling for speakers needs a rather large capacitance because of the low impedance of the speaker, such as the 100 µF used here.

Ceramic capacitors of such size have a strong dependence of capacitance on their instantaneous voltage.

At frequencies well above the highpass corner frequency, the voltage across the capacitor will be close to 0 V at all times, but for frequencies near the cutoff, the capacitor will see considerable bias voltage. As a result, a ceramic capacitor will transmit bass frequencies very non-linearly. This is audibly offensive because the harmonics of the bass frequencies mix into the prominent mid content.

When using a ceramic capacitor for output AC coupling, and aiming for high fidelity audio reproduction, the ceramic capacitor should have at least ~3x the capacitance of the electrolytic specification.

Electrolytics on the other hand have appreciable ESR at low frequencies, so they could damp the bass frequencies, but not distort them. It is not unheard of for a 100 µF electrolytic to have bass frequency ESR in the range of 4-8 Ω, so they would attenuate bass response by as much as 50 % for typical speaker impedances. However, this is much less offensive on the ears.

For clicks and beeps, though, all the hifi considerations above are sidenotes. The cap choice will color the sound but it will be always audible.

Answer (score 8):

High dielectric constant ceramic caps (everything except C0G) have high variation of capacitance with voltage so this will add a significant amount of distortion (think 20% at least). It would be completely useless for normal audio.

If it's just for beeps, who cares. It may in fact make the beeps sound more interesting.

If thickness is important you could also use a piezo buzzer instead of a loudspeaker. Piezos don't mind DC, they're capacitors. But they're not loud and only produce high frequency, so maybe not what you want.

Comment: AFAIK piezos are significantly louder near their resonant frequency - keep that in mind

Comment: @bobflux So would a C0G cap have a more linear frequency response comparable to that of an electrolytic?

Comment: C0G is very close to the perfect capacitor but it is only available in tiny values.

Answer (score 7):

It won’t matter much, provided the capacitor really has the advertised capacitance. The capacitance of a tiny 100uF cap might drop by 80% with 5V across the cap, so you might get some funny effects at low frequencies and/or extreme temperatures.

I suggest giving it a try. Clicks and beeps are not Golden Ear audiophile territory. It could be simulated with a sophisticated capacitor and speaker model, but it’s hard to predict what the human ear and associated brain processing would do with that waveform.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can use whatever capacitor you like with this amplifier and it won't reduce much the audio quality (given class deep-B the quality is poor to start with).

On the other hand, if the whole idea is to beep and click, you can go as bare as a single transistor and the speaker. Just remember to leave the the mcu output low after the beep.